# Automatically Activate Plugin in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Can I create a module for NetBeans that runs in the background as soon as the user opens the NetBeans IDE? For example, I am building a plugin that captures the source code of the active JTextComponent (active code editor) in NetBeans, but I would like this plugin to always run in the background without having to be activated by the user clicking a button or pressing some key combination.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just create a "Install.java" inside the root package of your module and subclass it with `ModuleInstall` class, then start a process that runs continuously inside the `restored()` methods. The `restored()` method gets called on module installation and everytime netbeans starts. So your process will start as soon as the module is loaded in Netbeans.

[ModuleInstall](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/ModuleInstall.html)

Also checkout this section from [DevFaqModulesGeneral](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesGeneral).

> Programmatic registration - ModuleInstall classes The module system
>   allows you to provide a ModuleInstall class, which runs some code
>   during  startup or when the module is loaded, and can run cleanup code
>   when it is uninstalled or  disabled. This is the least desirable way
>   to do things, because running code on startup means  slowing down
>   startup. Before you use such a class, be sure there is no declarative
>   way to do  what you're trying to do; see:
>   [DevFaqModulesDeclarativeVsProgrammatic](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesDeclarativeVsProgrammatic)
>
> To have some code run on startup/installation/uninstallation/etc., add
>   a line like the  following to your module's manifest file:
>
> `OpenIDE-Module-Install: org/netbeans/modules/paintcatcher/PaintCatcherModule.class`
>
> This line should be part of the group of lines at the top of the
>   manifest, with no blank  lines before it. It is a pointer to a class
>   file inside the module. The class file must extend  the class
>   org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall. There is a wizard in the
>   development support to  create and register such a class for you.